# GET request array to table in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I'm trying to create an `html` table based on the results from an array from a `GET` request.  I have tried for loops and I have tried Java examples, but the results are always displayed as a long string (or if I return the results as `dd($response)` it only returns one row.  I was wondering if there is a problem with the way format the array is returned:

```
{   "results":
[

    {   
        "column1":"TEST1",
        "column2":"DATADATADATA",   
        "time":"2017-02-27T16:25:03.1230000Z"
    },
    {   
        "column1":"TEST2",
        "column2":"DATADATADATA",
        "time":"2017-07-03T02:48:29.8300000Z"
    },
    {
        "column1":"TEST3",
        "column2":"DATADATADATA",
        "time":"2017-07-19T15:09:27.0900000Z"}
]
```

}

This is one example I tried in PHP:

```
$reponse = array(print_r($response));


for ($i = 0; $i < count($reponse); $i++) {
    for ($l = 0; $l < count($reponse[$i]); $l++) {
        echo $reponse[$i][$l];
        echo "<br/>";
    };
};
```

Comment: Show us what you tried!

Comment: This is one example that I tried (only returns one long string):$reponse = array(print_r($response));


    for ($i = 0; $i < count($reponse); $i++) {
        for ($l = 0; $l < count($reponse[$i]); $l++) {
            echo $reponse[$i][$l];
            echo "<br/>";
        };
    };

Comment: Are you wanting to build the table in the backend or the frontend?  Because your php looks like it will not be returning valid json, which the frontend usually would be expecting.  How does the json you included at the top relate to the script at the bottom?

Comment: @Taplar - the top is the result of $response.

Comment: So the top json is the json that prints if you do json_encode($response)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert JSON to an array:

```
$array = json_decode($data, true);
```

Then you'll be able to iterate over it:

```
@foreach ($array['results'] as $element)
    {{ $element['column1'] }}
    {{ $element['column2'] }}
    {{ $element['time'] }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: This returns an error: {Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)}

Comment: disregard, I had it in the wrong place.  This get me closer I think, it removes the array elements and only returns the results, but it is still returned as one long (string?).

Comment: @user2796515 it's not a long string, `{{ $var }}` is just displaying the data. You can do `<div>{{ $element['column1'] }}</div>`, for example. In this case, you'll get many lines. Add whatever HTML layout you want. It's just an example.

Comment: Undertsood. I think this will work, I will accept your answer and update if I get it working completely!

Comment: I didn't even have to apply CSS once applying your answer.  I surrounded them in <div>s with a class and they separated out.  Now I can apply some CSS and I am all set.  Thank you!